# Selection on second spinner not working

Tags: android, android-spinner, ormlite

I am developing a page with 2 spinners, where the first spinner has some category populated from DB. 
 Based On the value selected from spinner1, the selectedCategoryName is passed in the method setReportNamesContent().
 I am also getting the values populated in the second spinner, **but I am unable to do the selection in the 2nd spinner**.
 My idea is to pass both these selected values on click of a button, but always the 1st value from the 2nd spinner is getting  passed on click of the button.

```
protected void setReportCategory(String loginName) {        
        map = DBManager.getInstance().reportCategoryListByLoggedInUser(loginName);      
        reportCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(reportCategoryList);
        reportCategorySpinnner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ReportCategoryList);
        reportCategorySpinnner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reportCategoryList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        reportCategorySpinnner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
    switch(parent.getId()){     
    case R.id.ReportCategoryList:
        selectedCategoryName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        break;
    case R.id.ReportNameList:
        selectedReportName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        break;
    }   

if(!isEmptyOrNull(selectedCategoryName))
        setReportNamesContent(selectedCategoryName);
}   

private void setReportNamesContent(String selectedCategoryName) {
    reportNameList = map.get(selectedCategoryName);
    Collections.sort(reportNameList);
    reportNameSpinnner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ReportNameList);
    reportNameSpinnner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reportNameList);
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    reportNameSpinnner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
}
```

I had already reffered various question in this site and tried all of them and are not working. Please advice for a working answer

Comment: where u are trying to get selected value from both spinner ?

Comment: I am fetching the value from DB and storing them in a Map.
Values from the 1st spinner is the map's key.
Values in the 2nd spinner is the maps's value based on the above key.
//Key Retrieval
map = DBManager.getInstance().reportCategoryListByLoggedInUser(loginName);  
  reportCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());

//Value Retrieval
reportNameList = map.get(selectedCategoryName);